# scale floating divs at same height

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<div class="exwrap">
    <div class="listpages"> </div>
    <div class="excerpt"> </div>
</div>`
```

and css:

```
.listpages {
    width: 28%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.excerpt {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I want .listpages, and .excerpt to have the same heights, but this only works if I have .exwrap fixed height, but I need to have dinamic heights and the smaller one to have the height of the bigger one.

thanks.

Comment: use display: table or flex without float to get this behavior, else use js to check highest height and applie it to those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with floats, but possible with table cells ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j79e8/)):

```
.listpages {
    width: 28%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.excerpt {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```